# How to create drop-down list with bound a table column

Tags: bootstrap-modal

Am new in mvc , bootstrap I want to know how to create a bootstrap drop-down list with product table cloumn product name thanks

Comment: You can use https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp